# Can't find mb_protocol module for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I've been trying to install **PythonToolkit** on Linux, but I've encountered some problems. Whenever I try to run the PTK.pyw I get the error: `No module named 'mb_protocol'`.

Now, I've googled the name but I haven't been able to find a module named mb_protocol. I did however find another stackoverflow post that mentioned the same module.

The creator of the post told me that he had found the module, but unfortunatly he can't remember where.

So if anybody knows how I should go about installing this module, please do tell.

Comment: It's right there: `ptk_lib/message_bus/mb_protocol.py`. Have you properly installed `PythonToolkit`?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, but I'll check again

Comment: I've stumbled upon another problem, so when I ran the install script (setup.py), I ran it with python 3.9... but it appears that I need to run it in python 2.x. Problem is, I can't install wxpython to python 2.7. So I don't quite know what to do about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxpython+python-2.7

Comment: wxPython 3 and 4.0 still support Python 2.7. wxPython 4.1 stopped  supporting 2.7.

Comment: So if I install wxpython 4.0 I should be fine

Comment: Depends on what wx APIs are used by PythonToolkit. [The hompage](http://pythontoolkit.sourceforge.net/) says `wxPython (version 2.8+)`.

Comment: So, whenever i use pip (pip2 to be specific) I get the error ```invalid command 'egg_info'```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+invalid+command+egg_info